# Display UILabels with input from UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uilabel, constraints, uistackview

Currently, I have a `UITextField` with an `Add` button at the end. The purpose of this textfield is for the user to enter word and for that word to be centered in a `UILabel`. Below is the visual :

[image: UITextField w/UILabels]

I have the 3 `UILabels` embedded in a `Stack View` and each `UILabel` is hidden until user types something and presses `Add` button. Running simulator made me realize that if I keep one of them hidden it totally messes up the alignment of the other two. This is due to `equal centering` in the `Stack View` which made me question myself if this is right approach for what I want to achieve. I tried other distributions for the `Stack View` as well but no luck. Thoughts?

Comment: So your question is only about laying out the labels, correct? It has nothing to do with the text field and updating the labels from the text field.

Comment: Yeah, updating the labels via textfield was for more context. Only about laying out the labels

Comment: Did you try fillEqually?

Comment: Why not just set the alpha on the labels as needed?